# performBlockAndWait and the Main Context: canonical solution

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I have an application with Core Data where I frequently use:

```
[[MyCoreDataStore defaultStore].mainQueueContext performBlockAndWait:^{
     // perform some operations
     [MyCoreDataStore saveMainQueueContext];
}];
```

During an external code audit it was pointed out that `performBlockAndWait:` on the main context was wrong.

I was reading some questions from StackOverflow but could not find the canonical way to handle concurrency and not block the main context

[Core Data main context concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009865/core-data-main-context-concurrency)

[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait: doesn't execute on background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831946/nsmanagedobjectcontext-performblockandwait-doesnt-execute-on-background-thread)

[performBlockAndWait On Child Context with Private Queue Deadlocks Parent on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070111/performblockandwait-on-child-context-with-private-queue-deadlocks-parent-on-ios)

[Multiple contexts in the main thread: why and when use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091375/multiple-contexts-in-the-main-thread-why-and-when-use-them)

So what's the canonical way to deal with concurrence and keep the main context unblocked?

Comment: Who says `performBlockAndWait:` is wrong on the main context?

Comment: @TomHarrington, anything that blocks the main thread is wrong (for varying levels of "wrong"; exceptions always exist).

Comment: There is no canonical method, which is why you find so many different answers.  My preferred setup is to never write on the main context, and use it only for reads.  When you need to respond to changes initiated from the main thread, use an NSFetchedResultsController, or have the method which does the work call a completion callback when it's done.